# GET/POST requests missing parameters on form submit

Tags: php, post, get

This one is driving me crazy. I've tried several different solutions to no avail. Basically what is happening is that, when I submit a form, the request is being sent with no parameters.  I've tried both POST and GET and have monitored the requests with Firebug. Here's some sample code:

```
<form action="/year/" id="year-form" method="get">
    <select class="dropdown" id="year" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
    </select> 
</form>
```

Perhaps I should note that this is on a WordPress based site and I am directing the request back to the page  from which it came.  Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You missed the name attribute for the `<select>`.

Comment: Sometimes, it's the simplest things that get you.

Comment: Your missing the name attribute for the select element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not submitted because it is missing a name attribute:

```
<select class="dropdown" id="year" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="year">
```

So it has nothing to do with Wordpress.